# Cannot implicitly convert type DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interface, dbcontext

I have a context that contains many DbSets. Some of these DbSets implement an interface called IActivity which contains a number of common fields such as TimeReceived, TimeSent.

In my controller, I need to read values from one of the context DbSets but I don't know which one until runtime. So I created the following FactoryClass:

```
public static class ActivityFactory
{
    public static DbSet<IActivity> GetDbSet(BAMContext context, BizTalkApplicationEnum previousApplication)
    {
        switch (previousApplication)
        {
            case BizTalkApplicationEnum.Erp:
                return context.ErpRecs;
            case BizTalkApplicationEnum.Scip:
                return context.ScipRecs;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The IActivity interface is defined as follows:

```
public interface IActivity
{
    string ActivityID { get; set; }
    string InterchangeId { get; set; }
    DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    DateTime? TimeReceived { get; set; }
    DateTime? TimeSent { get; set; }
    string RoutingSource { get; set; }
    string RoutingTarget { get; set; }
    string RoutingToClient { get; set; }
    string RoutingMaster { get; set; }
    string ReceivePort { get; set; }
    string SendPort { get; set; }
    string RoutingMessageType { get; set; }
}
```

... and the BAM Context:

```
public class BAMContext : DbContext
{
    public BAMContext()
        : base("BAMPrimaryImportConString")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Database.SetInitializer<BAMContext>(null);
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Erp> ErpRecs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Scip> ScipRecs { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is, I get the following compilation error:
on the return statements within the case:

```
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TVS.ESB.BamPortal.DomainClasses.BAM.Erp>' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TVS.ESB.BamPortal.DomainClasses.BAM.IActivity>'
```

Could anyone please let me know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error?

Comment: Compilation error on this line: "return context.ErpRecs;" and this line: "return context.ScipRecs;"

Comment: Okay. You wrote "*Some of these DbSets implement an interface called IActivity*", do the DbSets implement that interface, or the models it encapsulates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible and you cann't convert `DbSet<Foo>` to `DbSet<IFoo>`.

The workaround may be to choose right `DbSet` first and materialize the data (execute the query). Then you can create new list `List<IActivity>` from a `List<Erp>` or `List<Scip>` using a covariance feature: [Cast List<T> to List<Interface>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925400/cast-listt-to-listinterface)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to work with a generic constraint:

```
public static class ActivityFactory
{
public static DbSet<T> GetDbSet<T>(BAMContext context, 
             BizTalkApplicationEnum previousApplication) where T: class, IActivity
{
    switch (previousApplication)
    {
        case BizTalkApplicationEnum.Erp:
            return context.ErpRecs;
        case BizTalkApplicationEnum.Scip:
            return context.ScipRecs;
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Your next problem will be accessing the properties from `IActivity` on the dbset you get back though, maybe my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872023/check-if-entity-implements-interface-and-add-predicate-in-generic-repo/34877162#34877162) can help you with that.